# Define DataGrid.InputBindings for all DataGrids in application

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

is there a way to define `DataGrid.InputBindings` for all `DataGrid`s in my application? I have my own command therefore I place:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
   <KeyBinding Command="{Binding MyOwnCommand}" Key="Delete"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

in every `DataGrid`... I've tried to set this as style without any success.

Thank you in advance!